# How do I set up my own dns record server?

Tags: linux, dns

I have the domain name example.com and I want to be able to configure my linux vps to handle what subdomain points to what IP.

For an example I want to be able to set test1.example.com to point to 99.99.99.99. I know I can just use my domain register's DNS to do this but I want to be able to quickly change/add/delete records.

Someone has recommended me to use BIND but it doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: You should ask this qusetion on SuperUser or ServerFault, but not here.

Comment: If you want your VPS to handle other ip addresses, you can simply add them to /etc/hosts

Comment: Seems reasonable to ask it here, particularly if it involves configuration of `bind`, `dnsmasq`, etc. as that satisfies the [on-topic requirement](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "Using or administering a *nix desktop or server"

Comment: @Vinz: he really should ask this question on Google. Granted, just putting the question, you will have to read a few articles. But if you put "bind" behind this question you get this fine tutorial as the first result: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04   (i couldn't remember how to markdown links to save my life!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your own DNS, you would have to:

- understand how DNS works.  The O'Reilly book [DNS & Bind](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) is a good start.
- install bind, dnsmasq, nsd, or similar authoritative name server
- configure it to serve your domain
- test it and make sure it's working (e.g. by doing `nslookup`s from the server itself)
- either update your domain at your registrar's web site so
  that the `NS` (nameserver) records point to your server, or ask your registrar to do it.

NOTE: you really should have at least two different nameservers (in case one is down or unreachable), preferably on two separate networks.  Check to see if your registrar offers DNS secondary service - if so, you'll have to configure your DNS server to allow XFER requests from their DNS servers.